# C++ inheritance (overriding constructors)

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, constructor, compiler-errors

I am learning OpenGL w/ C++.  I am building the asteroids game as an exercise.  I'm not quite sure how to override the constructors:

**projectile.h**

```
class projectile
{

protected:
    float x;
    float y;

public:

    projectile();
    projectile(float, float);

    float get_x() const;
    float get_y() const;

    void move();
};
```

**projectile.cpp**

```
projectile::projectile()
{
    x = 0.0f;
    y = 0.0f;
}

projectile::projectile(float X, float Y)
{
    x = X;
    y = Y;
}

float projectile::get_x() const
{
    return x;
}

float projectile::get_y() const
{
    return y;
}

void projectile::move()
{
    x += 0.5f;
    y += 0.5f;
}
```

asteroid.h

```
#include "projectile.h"

class asteroid : public projectile
{
    float radius;

public:
    asteroid();
    asteroid(float X, float Y);
    float get_radius();
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "asteroid.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    asteroid a(1.0f, 2.0f);

    cout << a.get_x() << endl;
    cout << a.get_y() << endl;
}
```

error I'm getting:

```
main.cpp:(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `asteroid::asteroid(float, float)'
```

Comment: Where did you define the asteroid constructors?

Answer (score 1):

You need a `asteroid.cpp`.

Even though inheriting from `projectile`, for non-default constructors (i.e., `asteroid(float,float)`), you still need to define the child class constructor.

You'll also need to define `get_radius`, as it's not defined in your base class.

Here's how that might look (I've taken the liberty of passing values for radius into both ctors):

```
#include "asteroid.h"

asteroid::asteroid(float r)
    : projectile()
{
    radius = r;
}

asteroid::asteroid(float x, float y, float r)
    : projectile(x, y)
{
    radius = r;
}

float asteroid::get_radius()
{
    return radius;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `:` syntax to call the parent's constructor:

```
asteroid(float X, float Y) : projectile (x ,y);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, just figured it out.

I actually don't have asteroid constructors defined because I thought they would inherit. But I think I have to do the following in asteroid.h:

```
asteroid(float X, float Y) : projectile(X, Y){];
```

Comment: or create a `asteroid.cpp`, and do so there. I'm also pretty sure, based on your design, that you're going to want `float r` passed to both `asteroid` ctors to initialize your radius member.

Comment: I've added it to my posted answer, just to make it more [acceptable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer). (BTW, your own answer actually acceptably answers your question, so I [upvoted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it.)